# How to add views to exception doctrine

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

When I run the composer command test:prepare I get an error
`An exception occurred while executing 'TRUNCATE v_my_views CASCADE'`

`SQLSTATE[42809]: Wrong object type: 7 ERROR:  "v_my_views" is not a table`

How to tell doctrine that this is a view and with a command `console doctrine:fixtures:load -n --group=main --em=default --purge-with-truncate` add this to the exception

I didn't find anything interesting that would help my problem.

Comment: This id **not** a problem; just remove the `truncate` on the view. A view cannot be truncated as it is not persisted. A view is basically a stored query and that query is run every thin the view is accessed.